# SpacyEntityExtractor is not recognising time entities correctly

Tags: spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, named-entity-extraction

Rasa v - 0.15

OS - Mac OS

text - set an alarm at 3 am

entity = CARDINAL

value = 3

We can see that expected entities from text should be-

entity = TIME

value = 3am

Why it showing wrong result?

Model used in spacy - 'en_core_web_md'

Pipeline that I am using is -

`language: "en"
pipeline:
- name: "SpacyNLP"
  model: "en_core_web_sm"
  case_sensitive: false
- name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
- name: "SpacyEntityExtractor"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
- name: "CountVectorsFeaturizer"
- name: "EmbeddingIntentClassifier"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the elements of the stack that are not Spacy, but as far as Spacy goes: the models are not always correct. They use probabilistic approaches to determine the category of a Named Entity.

You can experiment with larger models (such as en_core_web_lg), but they are more expensive computationally. Alternatively, you can think about training the NER-model to be better fit for your purpose. Spacy.io offer a tool for this, it is called Prodigy I think. Either way - without extensive training it is still a challenge to create totally robust Named Entity Recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to try out rasa/duckling. This is using the entity extractor from wit.ai and it is very nice and powerful for extracting time and date entities. For this, it is necessary to run a separated docker container and include it in your pipeline configuration in your nlu_config.yml and to specify the endpoint of this docker container in your endpoints.yml

Comment: we can't use duckling in our internal environment